# Excel Column Discrepency Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have no idea how to write this so i thought i would ask here, i have a spreadsheet which contains a component name and a manufacturers reference. I need to write a macro which checks make sure that the manufacturers reference is not used for any other component names.

For example the following is allowed:

```
Component Name              Manufacturers Reference
Scalpol                     SC001
Scalpol                     SC001
Scalpol Two                 SC002
```

As you can see above the 2 scalpol rows have the same manufacturers reference, but the manufacturers reference is not allowed to be used for any other parts except scalpol. For example:

```
Component Name             Manufacturers Reference
Scalpol                    SC001
Scissors                   SC001
```

The above would not be allowed so would need to set an error integer to be 1

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL:

```
SELECT S2.Component_Name, 1 as Error FROM [Sheet1$] as S1 
INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] as S2 ON 
S1.Manufacturers_Reference = S2.Manufacturers_Reference and 
S1.Component_Name <> S2.Component_Name 
WHERE S1.Component_Name < S2.Component_Name
```

You can create the query with Microsoft Query (the Data tab in the Excel ribbon) - see here:
https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e

Or feel free to use my Add-In: http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/

Comment: I already have a macro which does some other checks though which i have already written and working, so i need to do it in vba so it can go in the macro with the rest of the validation.

Comment: Still valid - create the query and in the VBA macro refresh it (the query becomes a refreshable query table) and do a for each through the rows. Better and more efficient than writing it from scratch